# Get PublishingPassword for website with PowerShell for new Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I used to use `Get-AzureWebsite -Name myportal` to get `PublishingPassword` what I can use inside Visual Studio to publish the WebApp to the cloud.

But now I was assigned with a new azure subscription that is not seen with the old azure command set (i.e. `Get-AzureSubscription`).

However this subscription is visible by `Get-AzureRmSubscription` (with "Rm" keyword). But `Get-AzureRmWebApp` doesn't contain `PublishingPassword` property.

Is there any other way to get `PublishingPassword` with new command set (that contains "Rm").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cmdlet you are looking for is `Get-AzureRmWebAppPublishingProfile` At the time I looked for a more direct method, but didn't turn one up. It is a little bit convoluted, but it works. (it doesn't actually write anything to file, but as I recall it choked if it wasn't included)

This is what I did with it...

```
function Get-FTPCredentials 
{
    $Xml = [xml](Get-AzureRmWebAppPublishingProfile -OutputFile test.xml -Format Ftp -ResourceGroupName $AppServiceResourceGroupName -Name $AppServiceWebAppName )
    $PublishProfile = $Xml.FirstChild.ChildNodes[1]   
    Write-Output ("FTP location is - " + $PublishProfile.publishUrl) 
    Write-Output ("FTP username is - " + $PublishProfile.userName)
    Write-Output ("FTP password is - " + $PublishProfile.userPWD)

    Write-Output ("Website URL is - " + $PublishProfile.destinationAppUrl)
}
```

Comment: A bit difficult to use (required OutputFile, what for...), but thx

Comment: Someone might have a better solution yet, that worked for me though

Answer (score 0):

Quick flow to get publishing password (`PublishingPassword`) for a website in Azure published via Visual Studio - manually by using PowerShell console:

```
Add-AzureRmAccount -TenantId 12343048-34cb-4322-b413-7b408837xxxx

Get-AzureRmWebAppPublishingProfile -Name myPortal -OutputFile test.xml -ResourceGroupName MyResourcesTestGroup
```

First command sets login to required tenant (directory) (i.e. adds your azure account to PowerShell session). Second gets the website (webapp) objects and prints publishing data including password.