# Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'SelectNodes'

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I have a script I am attempting to run against Azure subscriptions. The script grabs the published profile settings, such as the username, password and url to FTP a file up to that directory. I grabbed the syntax directly from a Microsoft document outlining exactly how to do so. Please see this link for use of xml with null output file: [Msft.Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scripts/app-service-powershell-deploy-ftp)

Unfortunately, I am getting an error stating:

> Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'SelectNodes'.

I am not sure why this is happening. Thanks!

```
$appdirectory="<app directory>"
$webappname="<webapp name>" ##"mywebapp$(Get-Random)"
$location="East US"
$ResourceGroupName="<resource group name>"

# Get publishing profile for the web app
$xml = (Get-AzureRmWebAppPublishingProfile -Name $webappname `
-ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
-OutputFile null)

# Extracts connection information from publishing profile
$username = $xml.SelectNodes("//publishProfile[@publishMethod=`"FTP`"]/@userName").value
$password = $xml.SelectNodes("//publishProfile[@publishMethod=`"FTP`"]/@userPWD").value
$url = $xml.SelectNodes("//publishProfile[@publishMethod=`"FTP`"]/@publishUrl").value


#ftp test 2
$request = [Net.WebRequest]::Create("$url")
$request.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("$username", "$password")
$request.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::UploadFile 

# make sure to create the path or change the URL to file. 
$fileStream = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead("C:\tmp\test.txt")
$ftpStream = $request.GetRequestStream()

$buffer = New-Object Byte[] 10240
while (($read = $fileStream.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length)) -gt 0)
{
    $ftpStream.Write($buffer, 0, $read)
    $pct = ($fileStream.Position / $fileStream.Length)
    Write-Progress `
        -Activity "Uploading" -Status ("{0:P0} complete:" -f $pct) `
        -PercentComplete ($pct * 100)
}

$fileStream.CopyTo($ftpStream)

$ftpStream.Dispose()
$fileStream.Dispose()
```

I know there is a similar issue but its slightly different as I am following an example given by Microsoft documentation in which the output file is null in my case.

Comment: `-OutputFile null` doesn't look correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get PublishingPassword for website with PowerShell for new Azure portal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36329982/get-publishingpassword-for-website-with-powershell-for-new-azure-portal)

Comment: @JamesC. Please see the edited question along with official documentation using exact example with -OutPutFile null is used with no explicit .xml file. Thanks!

Comment: I had something similar with System.String and length. There is a difference between a property which doesn't require parentheses at the end and a method that does. I had to remove the parentheses in my case. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.length?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot find official documentation to support this but the answer comes [from a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36329982/get-publishingpassword-for-website-with-powershell-for-new-azure-portal). The error is correct. You are treating a string like xml. You need to explicitly cast that string to xml first, if it is indeed an xml formatted string.

```
$xml = [xml](Get-AzureRmWebAppPublishingProfile -Name $webappname `
-ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
-OutputFile null)
```

**Note:** most example of using that cmdlet use a real file name e.g. test.xml. However null is probably the string null in this case so it probably works. `-outputfile` is listed as optional anyway according to [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/get-azurermwebapppublishingprofile?view=azurermps-6.3.0)

Comment: thank you for the answer. You can check out the Microsoft doc pertaining to this exact script; note in their example, they aren't explicitly casting the xml to a string, they are setting the outputfile to null as well. [Msft.Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scripts/app-service-powershell-deploy-ftp) - It is my understanding of how this script works is the output file is null, which is then utilized in the extract portion of the script.

Comment: @DangeRuss I would add that to your question since your pulled this from official example which is an important detail. Could mean the doc is wrong. `$xml` is clearly a string in your case and, presumably, the one in the doc is as well.

Comment: Thanks! I added that to the question. I will try to add in the an output file to see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: My point in the last paragraph is you should be able to omit it as well.

Comment: yeah I understood, but I will also try to explicitly state the xml file as well.

Comment: looks like the casting worked! I am no longer getting the error at this point, so thank you!